# How come my crypto's hash is jumping between two hashes?

Tags: node.js, hash

I'm getting either of the two:

- `body ==>  ef41c6e9a687de63acba3cd120737f18`
- `body ==>  3f952f0ca3875f634206563187bcd06d`

How is that possible? I've tried with sha1 and get the same results(two diff hash).

```
var request = require("request")
,   crypto  = require("crypto")
;

module.exports.run = function (event, context, cb) {
    return action(event, context, cb);
};

var action = function (event, context, cb) {    
    var invalid = "url of image that about 50x50";
    request.get(invalid, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            checksum(body);
        }
    });

    return cb(null, event);
};

function checksum (str) {
    console.log("body ==> ", crypto
        .createHash('md5')
        .update(str, 'utf8')
        .digest('hex')
    );
}
```

Comment: That's probably because you're getting two different responses. Write them to a file and diff them to see where they differ.

Comment: didnt download the files yet. but from what i see, after 5-6 requests it changes from "3f9..." to "ef4..." then back to "3f9...". i'll try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're downloading binary data like that, you should know that by default `request` will convert the response to a (utf8) string. So it's possible that the image data is getting mangled in that conversion.

To solve that particular issue, you can force `request` to keep the response as a `Buffer` by explicitly setting `encoding: null` in your request config. For example:

```
request.get({
  url: invalid,
  encoding: null
}, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    checksum(body);
  }
});

// ...

function checksum(buf) {
  console.log("body ==> ", crypto
    .createHash('md5')
    .update(buf)
    .digest('hex')
  );
}
```

Comment: hmmm that seems to be the case. before i set encode to null, i would get a diff hash every 5-6 requests. now that has went away. thanks!